# Characterizing Orthogonal Linear Transformations

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, linear-transformations, inner-products

I am not sure how the dot product fits into the following question. Is it asking to show the relationship between orthogonal linear transformation and the dot product in R^2?

Question: Characterize all of the orthogonal linear transformation from R^2 to R^2 (with respect to the dot product).

Comment: The answer is likely to be that they are characterised by orthogonal matrices.

When it says that it is with respect to the dot product, it means that is the inner product we are working with when we say the linear transformations are orthogonal

Comment: Thank you, that really helps.

Comment: The definition of an orthogonal transformation is itself in terms of the inner product: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_transformation